# Github not respond with SSH

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh, linux-mint

I generated the SSH key and I put into Github

- I use Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon 64-bit

When I run

ssh -vT git@github.com

this respond that:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.128] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/lucas/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/lucas/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lucas/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lucas/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lucas/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lucas/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lucas/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lucas/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.6.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.6.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/lucas/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/lucas/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.252.128]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = es_AR.UTF-8
```

and this stay here for a long time

after this time this is what's happen

```
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = es_AR.UTF-8
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 3296, received 1560 bytes, in 601.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 5.5, received 2.6
debug1: Exit status -1
```

I want so solve this problem please

pd: sorry for my bad inglish :D

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can look a the github documentation https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ by following the installation is pretty smooth.

Comment: So this question should be closed as answered ;)

Comment: How does this address the question? Telling them to re-read the docs?